# Is there a function for searching numbers inside a string list without looping 2 times?

Tags: python, list, loops

Imagine some card games inside a list, like the one below:

```
list1 = ['1 of Spades', '1 of Diamonds', '2 of Hearts']
```

I was trying something like that but it didn't worked out:

```
popped = [s for s in list1 if s[:1] in list1.count(s[:1]) > 1]
```

How can I get all the same-value cards and remove them without looping 2 times? In this example, both '1 of Spades' and '1 of Diamonds' should be popped.

Comment: You have to loop twice, since if you only loop once, you can't pop the values before the current element.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your looking to avoid nested loops and are looking for an O(n) solution, you could use a Counter dictionary to determine the number of each card value and filter the list based on it afterward:

```
list1 = ['1 of Spades', '1 of Diamonds', '2 of Hearts']

from collections import Counter

counts = Counter( c.split(" ",1)[0] for c in list1 )
list1  = [ c for c in list1 if counts[c.split(" ",1)[0]] == 1 ]
```

output:

```
print(list1) 

# ['2 of Hearts']
```